# Format of a memory dump file?

Tags: c#, memory, dump

Using task manager, there is an option to "Create dump file". I'm thinking it may be a useful tool for automatically finding updated memory addresses in an MMORPG I'm developing a bot for. I'm curious as well as to what exactly this file contains, as the dump files from the game may contain details of the persons account. I don't wish to be accused of trying to obtain this information forcefully, so it would be helpful for me to know exactly what is in the file.

On top of that, how am I to tell where the code ends and the memory begins, without having access to the source code? I will most likely take the dump file using C# itself, so within a managed language, from a process which runs simultaneously, so I can obtain the base address if that is necessary, but of course I would much prefer to do this dynamically.

Comment: It is undocumented, you'll find *some* declarations in the DbgHelp.h SDK header file.  This is not to give you a hard time, it is undocumented so that Microsoft can *change* it without breaking your program.  You'll need to use the debug api to read the file.  This is not supposed to be easy in C# and, in general, not an effective way to look at "updated memory addresses".

Comment: That does make sense to me, considering what research I have done. Do you feel it would be a more productive use to read the entirety of the memory of the application starting from the base address? This will provide me with only the memory which I require (I can tell it where to start roughly, also where to finish - to within about 1MB accuracy, the program consuming about 32MB total). The memory itself contains certain structures which I'm aware of, but occasionally they do change so the memory addresses change each couple of months, and the process of finding them is tedious...

Comment: Another semi useful question, if the exe file is 4.8MB, and loads a .dat of 818KB into memory, as well as a .pic of around 7MB on startup. If the exe is only 4.8MB, does that mean that the other 31.2MB is actually memory used for dynamically allocated objects such as class instances and structs? If so, that seems like a very large amount to me, considering the largest chunk of memory I'm aware of is a 400 entry array, of 192 bytes per entry (77KB, ish)... Seems again to be somewhat half-truthish.

Comment: Have you read this post: http://moyix.blogspot.com/2008/05/parsing-windows-minidumps.html?  It points you to the [MINIDUMP_HEADER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680378(VS.85).aspx) which is the data structure for the header of the minidump file, which might be a good starting point for reading the file.